# Changing the spacing behaviour in Resharper to multi-line lambda in-the-spot expressions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

How to convert the ugly

```
Task t1 = new Task(() => {
                        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; ++i) {
                            Console.WriteLine(i);
                        }
                    });
```

to something more palatable, such as

```
Task t1 = new Task(() => {
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; ++i) {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
});
```

in Resharper?

Thanks

Comment: The first IMO is "beautiful".. don't change it :P

Answer (score 2):

Go to `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Other`, turn off `Align Multiline Constructs | Anonymous method body`. This is for ReSharper 7.1, maybe in previous versions you'd also need to look for some settings on the same page, but in `Other` section.

Comment: Thank you. The default settings make my eyeballs bleed.